# React Native warnings after upgrading to SDK 49 Expo

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

Hi i'm getting those warnings after upgrading my react native app to SDK 49

"transform" style array value is deprecated. Use space-separated string functions, e.g., "scaleX(2) rotateX(15deg)"

"shadow*" style props are deprecated. Use "boxShadow".

props.pointerEvents is deprecated. Use style.pointerEvents

How i can avoid that?

I tried to modify all the styles as asked but always having the same warnings.